# How can I rearrange csv file to appropriate data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api, csv

[Sample of output from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPmhy.jpg)

```css
def getStationDetails():
    # construct the url
    url = API_URL
    print("Fetching %s" % url)
    # fetch the page
    response = requests.get(API_URL)
    jdata = response.text
    return json.loads(jdata)
    
    CSV_FILE = "bikeoutput.csv"             # CSV 

#Function to write data to csv
def writeToCsv(data, filename="bike_output.csv"):
    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data_frame['time'] = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S",          gmtime())
    data_frame.to_csv(filename, header=False,             mode="a")
```

I am scraping City Bikes API for the city of Dublin and have written a function to write the data to a csv file.

I have used the requests function to get the data directly from the API and loaded it as JSON format.

Does anyone know how I can read in the CSV file and rearrange this to a data frame with appropriate headings? I want the data to be presented as a table with columns titled 'name' 'idx' 'timestamp' 'free bikes' 'bikes rented' 'id' etc.

Comment: Can you please share a sample of the output from this API?

Comment: @ZevAverbach I have included it there in my post :)